# How to convert "/Date(1490065200000)/" to "21/03/2017"?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Please check in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/4629/).

Code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var str = moment("/Date(1490065200000)/"); //Convert to "21/03/2017"
  console.log(str.toString());
});
```

Here docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/

Any Solution ?

Comment: `new Date("/Date(1490065200000)/".replace(/\D+/g, '')*1)` ?

Comment: @JaromandaX, no... Result should be: "21/03/2017"

Comment: yeah ... notice how I didn't a) post an **answer** and b) use moment in the comment ... give a man a fish vs teach a man a fish - but it's OK, you have a couple of free fish already :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hope i help you.**

```
var str = moment("/Date(1490065200000)/").format("DD/MM/YYYY");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Nice Jobs, Thank you

Comment: Does it work with the date and time? Example: "DD/MM/YYYY HOURS"

Comment: `var str = moment("/Date(1490065200000)/").format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");`

Comment: Firstly add, moment.js https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js [click open](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js)

Answer (score 1):

Add `.format("MM/DD/YYYY")` . Docs: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

UPD: `.format("DD/MM/YYYY")`, like @Tushar noticed in comment

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regexp with a capture group.

```
str = "/Date(1490065200000)/"
timestamp = parseInt(str.match(/Date\((\d+)\)/)[1])
formatted = moment(timestamp).format('DD/MM/YYY')
console.log(formatted)
```

Explanation of the regexp `/Date\((\d+)\)/`:

- `Date` will simply match string `Date`.
- There are two pairs of parentheses. The outer one is escaped, hence the backslashes. This will literally match the parentheses characters as they appear in the date string.
- The inner parentheses, because they are not escaped, delimit a *capture group*. These say "I want to keep whatever string this actually matches". The resulting match object will have the captured strings in an array, which we can reference with `[1]` to get the desired number.

Comment: It turns out this may be unnecessary. As Ashish Kadam's answer points out, moment knows how to parse that string directly. The regexp is not required. It can still be useful if you want to perform some validation.